# The right back-end for a distributable application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I am thinking of developing a CRM type database application in C# that I can sell to clients, and am considering using Microsoft SQL Server as the back-end.

I would like potential clients to have the option of having the back-end either local or on a hosted platform.  If they choose the hosted option - that would be fine as we/third-party, could provide the SQL/Server platform.  However, if they wish to run locally, I wouldn't want them to have to pay for the licencing of SQL (as well as for my software).

Is there a free distributable version of SQL Server, that is able to cope with up to 30(ish) users, and capable of quite a lot of work?  I was thinking about Express - but not sure if that would be the right path.

Any suggestions (SQL Server or otherwise) would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Microsoft's SQL express?

Answer (score 0):

There are some limitations in SQL Server Express (10Gb per database, 1Gb of RAM and only one physical CPU).

May I suggest MySQL, open source and works well with .Net as it supports Entity Framework.